# Decomposing spin $n$ into $n$ spin $1$'s

Tags: angular-momentum, quantum-spin, tensor-calculus, group-theory, representation-theory

I would like to write a spin $n$ field $\psi^n_m$ as a tensor field $\psi^{\mu_1\cdots\mu_n}$ (where $\mu_i=1,2,3$), and I have boiled down the problem to decomposing the state $|n,m\rangle$ into a sum of $n$ spin $1$ states. This decomposition should be unique.

I was wondering if there's a nice formula for this?

**Edit:** There has been some confusion of what I mean by my question. To make my question clearer, it was suggested that I write down the $n=2$ case. $|2,m\rangle$ can be obtained from many possible additions of spins. For instance, one could obtain it by adding spin $3$ and $1$ states together, or adding spin $3$, $1$, and $1$ states together. My question is specifically about what the $|2,m\rangle$ states look like given that they come from a sum of two spin $1$ states. This is easily done:

$$|2,2\rangle=|11\rangle$$
$$|2,1\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|10\rangle+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|01\rangle$$
$$|2,0\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}|1-1\rangle+\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}|-11\rangle+\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}|00\rangle$$
$$|2,-1\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|-10\rangle+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|0-1\rangle$$
$$|2,-2\rangle=|-1-1\rangle$$
Where on the rhs I have only indicated the $z$ component of each spin $1$.

Comment: Are you sure you have not reversed it, dyslexically, as it were? The symmetric Kronnecker product of *n* spin 1s includes a unique spin *n* in its Clebsch decomposition direct sum. Show your work.

Comment: @cosmaszachos if one direction is unique, the other should also be unique, since they are related by a unitary transformation.

Comment: Direction? Of what?

Comment: Direction meaning "this decomposed into that" vs "that decomposed into this".

Comment: You are using "decomposition" in a novel, off-mainstream, way. Perhaps it's worth spelling out exactly what you have in mind in your question. You are not just transposing a Clebsch.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain what you have in mind with *n* =2.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will edit my post in a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah... it is all a mismatch of language... I will first try to rectify your language as described in [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clebsch%E2%80%93Gordan_coefficients#Tensor_product_space), QM texts, and angular momentum books such as Edmonds, Rose, etc...

"Addition of spins" means Kronecker (~tensor) multiplying *n* spin multiplets, in your case, triplets. This huge representation (multiplet) reduces (~decomposes) to a direct sum of multiplets of varying spin *J*. For *n* =2, the tensor product in the uncoupled basis is denoted as
$$
  |j_1 \, m_1 ~ j_2 \, m_2\rangle \equiv |j_1 \, m_1\rangle \otimes |j_2 \, m_2\rangle,
  \quad m_1 \in \{-j_1, -j_1 + 1, \ldots, j_1\},
  \quad m_2 \in \{-j_2, -j_2 + 1, \ldots, j_2\}, 
$$
but, here, we take both $j_1=j_2=1$.

The Clebsch series projection (not decomposition, a strictly technical term defined above!) on a given total *J* in the coupled basis, then amounts to
$$
|2,2\rangle=|1\,1~1\,1\rangle . \tag{1}
$$
The coefficient
$$
\langle j_1 \, m_1 ~ j_2 \, m_2 | J \, M \rangle ,
$$
(=1 above!) is called a Clebsch-Gordan coefficient, connecting the uncoupled and coupled bases.

In your example, these C-G coeffs are found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_Clebsch%E2%80%93Gordan_coefficients#_j1_=_1,_j2_=_1), so from the first column of the second table,
$$
|2,1\rangle=| 1 \,1~10\rangle \langle  1 \,  1 ~ 1 \, 0 | 2 \, 1 \rangle +|1\, 0~1\,1 \rangle \langle 1 \, 0 ~ 1 \, 1 | 2 \, 1 \rangle = {1\over \sqrt{2} }   | 1 \,1~10\rangle   + {1\over \sqrt{2} } |1\, 0~1\,1 \rangle , \tag{2}
$$
equivalent to the second line of your idiosyncratic notation. And so on.

Now, you need not have consulted a lazy table to get this (2). *All* you had to do is apply the left and right hand sides, respectively, of a (coproduct) lowering operator
$$J_-=j_-\otimes 1\!\! 1 + 1\!\! 1 \otimes j_-$$
to the left and right hand sides of (1), respectively,
$$
\sqrt{2\cdot 3-2}~|2,1\rangle = \sqrt{1\cdot 2}~ (| 1 \,1~10\rangle   +  |1\, 0~1\,1 \rangle ), 
$$
and so on, lowering to the lower state, etc... The normalizations of the states are guaranteed by the normalized action of lowering operators.

You are then ready to generalize to *n*=3, and then, actually,  arbitrary *n*:
$$
|n,n\rangle = |1\,1 ... 1\,1 \rangle,\\
|n,n-1\rangle ={1\over \sqrt{n}} ( |1\,1 ... 1\,0 \rangle+...+  |1\,0 ... 1\,1 \rangle  ),\\ ... ,
$$
where you may easily insert the  omitted  *n-2* terms for the ellipsis, given
$$
J_-=j_-\otimes  1\!\! 1 ...\otimes 1\!\! 1 +~ ... ~+    1\!\! 1  \otimes  1\!\! 1   ...\otimes j_-  ~.
$$

If you were a combinatorics geek, you might organize your C-Gs into Catalan pyramids, etc, but why bother?

Comment: Thank you for standardizing my language and giving me the inspiration necessary to get what I believe is the correct formula! I will accept your answer and cite the answer here. For expressing the state $|n,m\rangle$ in terms of $n$ spin $1$'s, the coefficient in front of states $|1\cdots-1\cdots0\cdots\rangle$ with $k$ zeros is $2^{k/2}/\sqrt{\binom{2n}{n-m}}$ Here $0\leq k\leq n-m$ with $k\equiv n-m \,(\text{mod}\, 2)$

Comment: You seem to be on your way. I didn't check your formula, but *n* =3 should lead you there... Biedenharn and Louck might have such things...